# Make Button NOT change title color when pressed

Tags: swift, uibutton

I can't find any other question on how to prevent this, and nothing I've tried is working perfectly.

I want to make it so the title color of the text on my button is ALWAYS white (I will do some other styling to make this look good still).

But, every time I press on the button, the title color changes from white to grey. How can I stop this? Preferably in the storyboard file instead of programmatically.

Images for illustration:

Not pressed:

[image]

Pressed:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select -> **Type: Custom** in Attributes ispector

[image]

Comment: @mikeyaworski I don't think so. You can't expect a standard button to behave in a 'special' way, so it has to be custom...